# Self time in Visualvm takes longer than the rest

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, performance, visualvm

[image]

I run my program in debug mode and I found that CPU usage goes up for first method.
The rest methods take only small CPU usage.

Can anyone point me why the first method takes much higher CPU usage (almost 100%)? How can I decrease it?

Comment: show us your method

Comment: `public void myMethod(String paramName,Connection dbConn ){
  
  try{
   if( dbConn.isValid(10)){
        
    CallableStatement statement = dbConn.prepareCall("{call myStoreProcedure(?)}");
    statement.setString("param", paramName);
    statement.execute();
    System.out.println("Statement to create NgsScannedData : ");
    statement.close();
   }
  }catch(SQLException e){
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }`

Comment: Most of your method are calling other function. That's strange. Is it possible gc happens right when the calling stack is at the method? Upvoted cause I'm curious.

Comment: i don't call another method inside one method. I call only those java api method for sql statement.

Comment: All kinds of database connections etc. will use wall clock time, but not CPU time. You're only showing the wall-clock time, which just shows that your method takes the most time. However this question has still nothing to do with CPU usage.

Comment: what about the percentage ? sorry i'm newbie to visualvm

Answer (score 2):

Self time doesn't measure CPU usage. It measures wall-clock time. That's why there's `Total Time`, `Total Time (CPU)`, `Self Time` and `Self Time (CPU)`. `Self Time (CPU)` would be the interesting part when you're looking for hotspots in your code.

As an example, if you have a sleeping thread (only sleeping, with no work to do), it would give you `100%` for `Self Time` (and same time for total time), but `0` for CPU.

Comment: Calling Thread.sleep() is calling other function, and it's part of *Total Time* but  not part of *Self Time*.

Comment: `Thread.sleep();` calls a native method which will get the full `self time' without any CPU usage.